# PrettyPrint with Mutable Mapping

Tags: python, python-3.6, pretty-print

I had a nested dict in my project, which was printed via PrettyPrint (just throw the nested dict into it).

But this nested dict had to be replaced by nested MutableMapping Objects, because I needed to overwrite some MagicMethods.
But because it's an object now, it is just taking the first key and prints out, that the value is a my_dict object.

How can I PrettyPrint now such a MutableMapping Object with a dict attribute?

```
class my_dict(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self):
        print("dict was created")
        self.d = dict() # var where I want to store my key/values

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # do sth else
        print("Dict Element was set: Key:\t{}, Value:\t{}".format(key, value))
        self.d[key] = value
        return

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # do sth else
        print("Item was requested")
        return self.d[key]

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.d[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.d.__iter__()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.d)

    def sd(self, k, d):
        if k not in self:
            self[k] = d
        return self[k]
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pprint` just formats the string returned by `__repr__`, and prints it.
Add the following dunder method to your class.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.d.__repr__()
```

**Edited**

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
PrettyPrinter._dispatch[my_dict.__repr__] = PrettyPrinter._pprint_dict
```

`pprint` will print as though it was called with the inner `dict` `self.d`. `PrettyPrinter` has an internal dict called `_dispatch` which maps `class.__repr__` => `pprint_method`. So you have to add a pprint method for your class. In this case, I mapped `my_dict.__repr__` to the pprint method for `dict`, so `pprint` formats `my_dict` objects as if they were dicts.

`pprint` source code is in plain python [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/pprint.py).

Comment: I got my nested dict printed out, thx for that, but the format is not working right (no indents, no new lines and width seems to be ignored) and pprint.pformat is not changing anything. Any clue why this could be caused and how I get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete answer. I added a couple lines. Don't forget to delete `print("Item was requested")`, otherwise the line will appear everywhere.